# LaSalle calling Pride, King

Tags: character, ncis-new-orleans

In [NCIS: New Orleans](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3560084/), 1. am I hearing LaSalle correct when he calls Pride "King", and 2. why does he call him that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He calls Pride "King" because that is his [nickname](http://ncis.wikia.com/wiki/Dwayne_Cassius_Pride).

It is explained in the NCIS (mothership) episode that introduced the New Orleans team, ["Crescent City"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3548332/synopsis), Season 11 Episode 18:

> Down in NO, LaSalle explains to Brody how Pride got the name King:
>   When Pride first opened up the New Orleans NCIS office he made a big
>   drug bust and a local crew made him an honorary member and named him
>   King. LaSalle was a sheriff's deputy and King saved his life after
>   Katrina.

Comment: Thanks.  I must have missed that little bit and/or forgotten it.

Answer (score -2):

My belief is that he got the nickname King from being the frequent finder of the baby in the King cake when he was a child. He thus became King of the Mari Gras amongst the kids.

Answer (score -2):

The man's name is Pride. A group of lions is called a Pride and the lion is the King of the jungle. Therefore Agent Pride is called King.